# Как в phpstrorm вернуть хлебные крошки в меню?

Tags: phpstorm

Как вернуть это меню? когда то отключил теперь нужно и включить не знаю где.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `View-> Navigation bar`

Comment: Спасибо ) помог

Comment: Рад помочь.. :3

Comment: Шрифт в окне терминала phpStorm как увеличить не знаешь? и можно ли? Я  нашел терминал в настройках, но шрифта там нету